# how to show an array of model in view yii framework

Tags: php, arrays, yii

**invoice** is a view in **DB** and i want to show this view information in a **CGridView** form
 this is my action:

```
    public function actionInvoice()
    {
  $model= Invoice::model()->findAllBySql('select * from invoice where userid ='.Yii::app()->user->id);
  $this->render('invoice',array('model'=>$model));

}
```

and this is my view:

```
<?php var_dump($model)   ?>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'UserAccountnumber-grid',

'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'amount',
    'time',
    'status',
                )        


)    



);
?>
```

but when i run this code i got an error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function search() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\mypal\protected\views\user\invoice.php on line 5

i know this error is because of i send an array of model into the view but i dont know how to figure it out and show an array of models in a CGridView
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why `findAllBySql`?

may be

```
Invoice::model()->findAllByAttributes([
    'userid' => Yii::app()->user->id
]);
```

And findAllBySql and findAllByAttributes return array of ActiveRecord object.
if you want find only one row use `findBySql` or `findByAttributes`

but best way:

```
public function actionInvoice()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Invoice', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition' => 'userid=:userid',
            'params' => [':userid' => Yii::app()->user->id]
        ),
    );
    $this->render('invoice',array('provider'=>$dataProvider));
}
```

and view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'UserAccountnumber-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$provider,
    'columns'=>array(
         'amount',
         'time',
          'status',
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSqlDataProvider to get the data provider, and pass it to the CGridView widget.

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

The $model->search() autogenerated function returns a CDataProvider, but your $model, is not the Model class, is a result set of a SQL query.